# Umbraco foreach children of a child page

Tags: c#, loops, foreach, umbraco, children

I have news posts within a news page within a homepage on my content structure

#### Example:

Homepage
- News
 
-- News Posts

I'm looking to have some of the news feed on my homepage in a foreach statement. In my head it should be as simple as:

```
@foreach (var homenews in CurrentPage.Children.Children)
{
     if (homenews.Name == "News Post")
     {
         //Do some stuff//
     }
}
```

Obviously that doesn't work so has anybody got any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up getting the news page by its id and then getting it's children from there. The below code worked for me. Thanks guys.

```
@{
    var node = Umbraco.Content(1094);    
    <p>@node.Id</p> // output is 1094  
    foreach (var item in node.Children.Where("Visible").Take(3))

    {

         <p>@item.exampleText</p>

    }
    }
```

Comment: IMO it's bad practice to reference by ID. What happens if the page is replaced? It's much better to walk the tree and find the page by doc type alias.

Comment: The page I accessed by ID will never need to be changed for my project. So the above code is just what I want.

Comment: Absolutely fine, as I said only an opinion. Pages being replaced is not the only reason it's a bad idea though. E.g. Someone picking up the code will have no idea what page 1094 is. Where as 'walking the tree' will give the developer a clear relationship between the code and the target node. Also, as a developer, never say never :)

Answer (score 4):

When you're walking the tree you have to remember that a property (or method) like `Children` or `Descendants()` will return a collection of objects, so you can't just call `Children` of a collection. You can only call `Children` on a single object.

You can find the correct child of the homepage by using something like `var newsPage = CurrentPage.Children.Where(x => x.DocumentTypeAlias == "NewsListingPage")` and then extract the children of that page.

Comment: The logic of this makes perfect sense but I am struggling get my code to work. 

    @{ var newsPage = CurrentPage.Children.Where(x => x.DocumentTypeAlias == "News"); 
       
      foreach (var homepost in newsPage.Children)
        
       {
}}

Comment: Is it outputting anything at all? The code looks ok. You probably need to step through it with the debugger.

Comment: I also tend to add in null checks on the node collections `.WhereNotNull()` or `.Where(x => x != null)`. Also make sure that you have all the relevant references in your view. You could also try the `.Children()` method extension instead of the property call.

Comment: I get a server error: Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type

Comment: I got `Model.Content.Children.Where(x => x.DocumentTypeAlias == "NewsListingPage").Where("Visible")` working

Comment: @Kunal Yes, that would work if you only had access to the RenderModel passed to the view. The `CurrentPage` member is a property of the `RenderMvcController` (and `SurfaceController`) class so is only accessible in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reference the required node by **NodeTypeAlias** of it's Document Type.

So assuming the alias of the DocType of your News Posts is “NewsPosts” then...

```
@foreach (var homenews in @Model.Descendants().Where("NodeTypeAlias == \"NewsPosts\"")).Take(3)
{       
    <p>@homenews.Name<p>
}
```

...should return the name of the first 3 news posts.

Comment: Just remember that this approach is not considered good practice. Putting logic in your view is always considered a bad option. Instead, do the logic in a surface controller and assign the results to a view model / poco property,

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact scenario, this is how I got mine working. NodeByID was very useful nad -1 indicates the root

```
@foreach(var item in Model.NodeById(-1).Children)
    {
string itemName = item.Name;
switch(itemName)
{
    case "News":
        @* News *@
    <div id="News"> 
      <h3><a href="@item.Url">@item.Name</a></h3>
   @foreach (var newsPost in item.Children.OrderBy("UpdateDate desc").Take(4).Items)
        {
            <p>
            <a href="@newsPost.Url">@newsPost.Title</a>
             </p>
        }

    </div>
   }
}
```

Comment: This won't work because you are assuming that the News page is a child of the root which it isn't. It's a child of the homepage (which is a child of the root). It's bad practice to have your top level nodes as immediate children of the root.